# HTML tag <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am really new to this  tag. what i know about this tag is this tag insert a  page into other  page.

So I want to ask about the assets I include in a parent can affect the  child?

there is some examples of code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <body>
    <iframe>
        <script src="script2.js"></script>
    </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, does "script2.js" affect the parent's HTML?
or does "script1.js" effect the HTML inside  tag?

Comment: Until you've written a code to affect parent/child, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div>
           <script> 
               var x = document.getElementById('div1');
               console.log(x);
           </script>
        </div>
        <div id="div1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

=> What will be printed in console?
=> what happen If I declare the `<div id="div1"> </div>` before `<div> <script>...</script></div>`

When you get your answer, you can find the similarity between this example and Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The last script read supersedes any previous scripts. Thus is script1.js and script2.js are trying to do the same thing, the code will use script2.js.